# Waiting for table level lock on a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, myisam

The last few days, at random times my website has become very slow. I started to investigate the best I could. I saw that the MySQL process was using 85 - 95% of the available memory of my server (should I upgrade my memory also?).

I checked my MySQL process log, and I noticed a huge list of queries with:

> Waiting for table level lock

But what I also noticed, what that ALL of these queries with "table level lock", was only queries which had something to do with my table called `users`.

I have 20 other tables, with constant queries, but I don't see them on the list.. So I guess the problem is with the users table?

I want to know how I can improve the table, and eventually remove the table level lock?

I also ran this:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query_cache%';
```

Which resulted in this:

```
query_cache_limit
1048576
query_cache_min_res_unit
4096
query_cache_size
33554432
query_cache_type
ON
query_cache_wlock_invalidate
OFF
```

Please let me know what I can do to improve my database/mysql.

This is a list of the processes:

```
   | 228 | db_user | localhost | db_db| Query          |    5 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE createtime>'1396411200' OR createtime='1396411200'                  |
    | 229 | db_user | localhost | db_db| Query          |    4 | Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE users SET upline_clicks=upline_clicks+'1', upline_earnings=upline_earnings+'0.0000' WHERE use |
| 203 | db_user | localhost | db_db| Query          |    6 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SUM(cashedout) FROM users                                                                     |
| 204 | db_user | localhost | db_db| Query          |    4 | Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE users SET upline_clicks=upline_clicks+'1', upline_earnings=upline_earnings+'0.0000' WHERE use |
| 205 | db_user | localhost | db_db| Query          |    1 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='12055'                                                                 |
| 206 | db_user | localhost | db_db| Query          |    2 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='22530'                                                                 
| 197 | db_user | localhost | db_db| Query          |    3 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = 'ptc4life123' LIMIT 1                                       |
| 200 | db_user | localhost | db_db| Query          |    3 | Waiting for table level lock | UPDATE users SET upline_clicks=upline_clicks+'1', upline_earnings=upline_earnings+'0.0050' WHERE use |
```

This is basically what all the locked processes looks like.

Comment: Start adding indexes to users, particularly fields like user last name, dept, ID...anything that would be used often in queries.

Comment: Indexes? Care to elaborate a bit? (Sorry, I am still fairly new to MySQL)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During one of the slow periods, run this command:

```
show processlist;
```

This will show you the actual SQL commands that are running, and the places to look for in terms of adding indexes.  Post the longest running SQL if possible.

Adding an index will look like this:

```
 ALTER TABLE MYTABLE ADD INDEX idx_columnname (COLUMN_NAME ASC) ;
```

But you want to be careful not to do that during a production period.  At first glance, you want to do that on ID and username columns in the user table.

Comment: please see my updated question. I have included a list of the slow processes.

Comment: Great.  And what is this number when you run it?  SELECT count(*) FROM users

Comment: OK good.  The indexes will be created in less than 10 seconds most likely.

Comment: so I should create index on "ID" and "username"? 
ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX id (COLUMN_NAME ASC);
AND
ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX username (COLUMN_NAME ASC);

Is that correct?

Comment: Close.  You want this:  ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX idx_id (ID ASC); AND ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX idx_username (username ASC);

Comment: It would be good to know the rest of the WHERE statement....

UPDATE users SET upline_clicks=upline_clicks+'1', upline_earnings=upline_earnings+'0.0000' WHERE use |

Comment: Oh sorry! The rest of all is just either: "WHERE username=:username" OR "WHERE id=:id"

Comment: would it be possible to have a private chat about this? Is this allowed on StackOverflow, to exchange details?

Comment: No worries! Thanks, it worked in the end. My site speed has improved!

Answer (score 1):

Check the storage engine of the table .Change to  Innodb if possible as it cause only row level locking. 
The queries which are running may be forcing a table lock even if you are using innodb tables
if you are not using the index .

Comment: Can you please try to explain a little bit more about "index". How should I use them?

Comment: Index is a pointer to the data . It will be a binary tree(most commonly) having the full row as the leaf node. For example primary key is an index pointing to a single row. Difference is it will be sorted so that you dont have to go and do a full table scan to fetch the data.

Comment: If you are not indexing then it will work like the entire table will be locked as it is doing a full table scan instead of an index scan.

Comment: Check the documentation  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: Oh okay.. Should I only use INDEX on 1 row in the table? (Like 'userid' forexample)

Comment: If it is a primary key it will be already indexed. Create index based on your WHERE conditions . for example if it is like (user_id =1 and user_name ='test') then create an index like (user_id,user_name).But take a note that only one index is used by a table in a single query and too many indexes will make insert update and delete more slower .