# Waiting for table level lock - mysql

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to run a simple query `SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 1` and the process goes on without retrieving anything. I cannot do run any other queries for that specific table because they go on forever. I killed the session (using phpMyAdmin > Status) but still when I try to run the query again it still does the same thing.

Inside phpMyAdmin > Status on the process  I got this message:

> Waiting for table level lock

I run `SHOW OPEN TABLES;` which it says that table's In_use is 3.

Does anyone know why this happens?
Or any way to fix it?

I also tries `UNLOCK TABLES` but it didn't do anything

Comment: Can you share `show processlist;`?

Comment: only one row returned and info says: show processlist

Comment: Try switching to `InnoDB` aswell, if you haven't already. More info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809439/waiting-for-table-level-lock-on-a-mysql-table

Comment: not an option...

Comment: You can change to InnoDB in phpMyAdmin with just a few clicks. To convert your data tables from MyISAM to InnoDB in phpMyAdmin, you will select the table, click the “Operations” tab, and then choose InnoDB from the drop down box next to the “Storage Engine” type. Click “Go” and you are done!

Comment: no I mean this is not an option, I cant make that kind of change in this database as it is not mine

Comment: UNLOCK TABLES; ?

Comment: @noel293 doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command your MySql side

show processlist;

This will show all the processes holding on to the DB. This will also show you exact query.

Comment: only one row returned and info says: show processlist